# extract rows from text file and save it in separate files

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, awk, while-loop

i have a very big text files and i want to extract every two rows from it and want to save it in separate files and file name should be saved in the name firstrowfirstcolumn_firstrowfourthcolumn

```
10  25  6  3  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
11  25  6  8  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
12  25  6  3  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
13  25  6  3  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
14  25  6  3  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
15  25  6  4  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
16  25  6  4  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
17  25  6  4  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
18  25  6  4  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
19  25  6  4  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
20  25  6  5  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
```

for example 10_3.txt should contain

```
10  25  6  3  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
```

similarly 11_8.txt should contain

```
11  25  6  8  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
```

similarly 12_3.txt should contain

```
12  25  6  3  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
```

and so on

i tried the code below but it doesn't work

```
for file in input
do
awk 'NR==1,NR==2' $file
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, completely based on your shown samples only. Written on mobile so couldn't test it, should work I believe.

```
awk '
FNR%2!=0{
  close(output_file)
  output_file=$1"_"$4".txt"
}
{
  print > (output_file)
}' Input_file
```

OR make 2 variables which you need to take as output file name.

```
awk -v first="1" -v second="4" '
FNR%2!=0{
  close(output_file)
  output_file=$first"_"$second".txt"
}
{
  print > (output_file)
}' Input_file
```

***Brief explanation:*** Simply checking condition if line is odd in terms of line number then close previous output file and create new output file name as per current line's fields then printing everything to that output file.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
$ awk ' { fn=$1 "_" $4 ".txt" ; print > fn; getline ;print > fn }' glk.txt
$ cat 10_3.txt
10  25  6  3  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
$ cat 11_8.txt
11  25  6  8  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
$ cat 12_3.txt
12  25  6  3  1  8  5  2  1  6  1
99  26  7  4  1  8  8  1  2  8  1
$
```